# получение текущего уровня громкости и яркости экрана на java

Tags: java, аудио, экран

есть ли возможность в java получить вышеуказанные значения(не для андроид,а для ноутбука,пк и т.д.), и если да,то как?

Answer (score 1):

//получение текущей громкости

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int volume_level= am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

//яркости

```
int curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
```

Comment: прошу прощения за неточность касательно платформы,исправил вопрос,быть может и для пк/ноутбука есть возможность считать?

Comment: @Никита Крагель, в следующий раз уточняйте сразу. Насчёт пк - не знаю

Comment: @НикитаКрагель,
Насколько я знаю, для ПК без библиотек - никак.
Звук:
Audio.setMasterOutputVolume(0.5f); используя библиотеку
https://github.com/Kunagi/ilarkesto/blob/master/src/main/java/ilarkesto/media/Audio.java
Яркость (для Windows, и нужен Powershell):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880547/how-to-change-laptop-screen-brightness-from-a-java-application